# If method argument is a primitive int, then myArrayList.contains(primitiveArg) within a loop within a method is enormously inefficient or OK?

Tags: java, performance, autoboxing

I have code like this:

```
public int getDistanceToNumber(int number) {
    List<Integer> tuple5 = null;
    int distanceCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < allDraws.size(); i++) {
        tuple5 = allDraws.get(i).getTupleAsList();
        if (tuple5.contains(number)) {  // autoboxing primitive ?

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The question is - shall I make method argument Integer like `int getDistanceToNumber(Integer number)` for autoboxing from primitive into Integer to happen only once, or there is no performance issue.

This piece of code inside loop runs over 100K times...

Comment: Did you look at the generated bytecode and/or perform benchmarks?

Comment: Have you benchmarked this with JMH and determined that it's in need of optimization?

Comment: Don't change the method signature. Instead, you can create a local variable with the boxed `int` value. As for performance, the sequential search of the `List` is more of a problem. However, as others have suggested, don't micro-optimize the code without first analyzing the code by profiling it.

Answer (score 0):

You should test that under a [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

- You can avoid the boxing problem by using a `Integer.valueOf(int)` once and passing it to `List::contains(Object)`.
- The compiler may be efficient enough to understand that `number` is never changed and do that for you.

For the rest, without more information (type of `allDraws` ?), there might be other optimization to do before boxing conversion.